# Unable to compile NServiceBus 4.6.3

Tags: compilation, nservicebus

I am trying to build NServiceBus 4.6.3 (which I just downloaded from https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/4.6.3).
So according to the build instruction from README.md it is enough to compile the solution in Visual Studio.
However I receive a huge bunch of errors.

Some of them:

```
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\License.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\LicenseDeserializer.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\LicenseExpirationChecker.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\LicenseVerifier.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\RegistryLicenseStore.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\ReleaseDateReader.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\TrialStartDateStore.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\UniversalDateParser.cs' could not be found
'App_Packages\Particular.Licensing\UserSidChecker.cs' could not be found
```

And another:

```
The type or namespace name 'ObsoleteExAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    c:\dev\ESB\NSB\NSB-4.6.3\src\NServiceBus\IBus.cs    228 10  NServiceBus
```

I was trying to find ObsoleteExAttribute class but with no success. Where should I get it from?

Am I supposed to acquire the above files somehow separately? Why this is not mentioned anywhere in the NServiceBus documentation?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the pre-built binaries from the website?

Comment: I tried but there is information that my trial period has expired. If I want to use NSB with a free RPC license, is it enough to download the pre-built binaries from http://particular.net/nservicebus ?

Comment: Fill in the form to extend your trial, someone will be in touch and then explain that you want the free RPL approach.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the issue with package monitor, by installing "Obsolete.Fody" package.
Now the `ObsoleteExAttribute` is recognized. However other errors persist...